# From boundingBoxHelper to BoxHelper

Tags: three.js

in threejs r83, boundingBoxHelper has been deprecated, using BoxHelper instead. How do you get the box of the BoxHelper?

```
let boundingBox = new THREE.BoxHelper(mesh);
myObj.size = bounding.box.getSize(); // error
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to use `BoxHelper` and get the size of your renderable object, or mesh.

```
var box3 = new THREE.Box3();
var size = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse

...

var boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh );
scene.add( boxHelper );

box3.setFromObject( boxHelper ); // or from mesh, same answer
console.log( box3 );

box3.getSize( size ); // pass in size so a new Vector3 is not allocated
console.log( size )
```

three.js r.83